# Trying to Highlight Used Range of a Column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running into trouble highlighting a column's used range. The following code creates copies of two worksheets, removes some values and then is supposed to highlight certain columns.

```
Sub CreateAnalysisSheets()
    Dim cell, HlghtRng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ref, findLast, findThis As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    findLast = "2016"
    findThis = "2017"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(2)
        ActiveSheet.Name = Left(Sheets(1).Name, InStr(1, Sheets(1).Name, " ")) & "Analysis"
    Sheets(2).Copy After:=Sheets(3)
        ActiveSheet.Name = Left(Sheets(2).Name, InStr(1, Sheets(2).Name, " ")) & "Analysis"
    Sheets("RM Analysis").Select
        For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            If cell.Value = "NULL" Then
                cell.ClearContents
            End If
        Next cell
        For Each cell In Range("1:1")
            ref = cell.Value
            lastRow = Range("R" & Rows.Count & "C" & cell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            Set HlghtRng = Range(Cells(1, cell.Column) & Cells(lastRow, cell.Column))
            If InStr(1, ref, findLast) > 0 And InStr(1, ref, "YTD") = 0 Then
                HlghtRng.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
            End If
        Next cell
    For Each cell In Sheets(4).UsedRange
        If cell.Value = "NULL" Then
            cell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next cell
    Sheets("RM Analysis").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The problem comes at `lastRow = Range("R" & Rows.Count & "C" & cell.Column).End(xlUp).Row` where I get an `Method 'Range' of Object '_Global' Failed`. I've tried searching for ways to fix this issue, but everything I've tried (`ActiveSheet.Range` and `Sheets("RM Analysis").Range`) has yet to work.

Anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xlR1C1 syntax is fouling up your request for the last non-blank cell.

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, cell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
```

I would highly recommend that you avoid relying on the ActiveSheet and use explicit parent worksheet references. This can be made quite simple using `With ... End With` and preceding all `Range` and `Cells` with a `.` like `.Range(...)` or `.Cells(...)`.

Once you within a `With ... End With` statement, **all** of the references need to be prefaced with a `.`. Additionally, the following is not a string concatenation (e.g. `&`) but as .Range(*starting cell comma ending cell*) operation.

```
with worksheets("RM Analysis")
     ...
    Set HlghtRng = .Range(.Cells(1, cell.Column), .Cells(lastRow, cell.Column))
     ...
end with
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I definitely agree with the `With...End With` and have made those changes including the fix to the xlR1C1 syntax. Now I'm getting `Application-defined or Object-defined Error` on the `Set HlghtRng` bit. I'm not sure why something this simple is causing me this much trouble

Comment: See above for suggested modifications.

Comment: Perfect! Such a small but big change. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

this should do

```
Columns(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

change the number of column as to the column you wanna highlit

Comment: I don't want to highlight the entire column. Just to the last used row which is why I defined `HlghtRng`.

Comment: well then try this
HlghtRng.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 8